# Preventing double loading JS scripts (like React) when developing for Gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

Gutenberg is mostly made in JS, so I'm using `create-guten-block` to create some custom blocks. If multiple plugins use this to create blocks, is it a problem that these scripts get compiled and loaded for each plugin instance. Like React, being enqueued multiple times, doesn't it slow the page down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any WordPress-packaged scripts enqueued properly via `wp_enqueue_script` won't load multiple times. If two different plugins rely on the same dependencies, thanks to the enqueue logic, those dependencies will only be loaded once.

`create-guten-block` only contains javascript relevant to the custom block itself, and sets `wp-blocks`, `wp-i18n`, and `wp-element` (the abstraction layer WP uses on top of React) as its dependencies. See /src/init.php of the generated block code.